# Python Prime Numbers Loop

Tags: python, while-loop, primes, function

When running this code, I keep having an error. I would like to know what is wrong. The code has to be able to read words and integers and repeat the prompt(Please enter an integer >= 2: ') until it is greater or equal to 2. Thanks in advance.

```
def prime_number():

    prime_num = input('Please enter an integer >= 2: ')

    while not(prime_num.isdigit() and int(prime_num)<1):

        prime_num = input('Please enter an integer >= 2: ')

    for i in range(2,int(prime_num)+1):
        for x in range(2,i):
            if i%x == 0:
                break
        else:
            print (i)
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: When I try to run it, it is completely blank. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Considering that you're repeating until the number is not < 1, I'm not sure how you even get to the code that has an error…

Comment: Try calling the function.

Comment: You'll need to *call* the function at the bottom of your script. Add `prime_number()` to the bottom with no indentation

Comment: @Jay: You're using Python 2.x; the question is pretty clearly for 3.x.

Comment: @dazedconfused: You indented the `else` to match the `if` instead of the `for`, which broke his code. I've dedented it back.

Comment: @DatOneGuy Is your program trying to determine if that number is prime?

Comment: @abarnert: Didn't notice that, sorry

Comment: The program terminates or is blank when I use def and I get stuck in the loop and can't break it.

Comment: @DatOneGuy: That last comment is way too vague to understand. What does "when I use def" mean? If the program terminates, how are you stuck in a loop? What are you trying to do to break it?

Comment: @DatOneGuy: If you're complaining that no matter what you enter, it keeps telling you to enter another number, I already explained that in my first comment. If you're complaining that the program terminates without doing anything visible at all, even asking for a number, rpattiso explained that.

Comment: @abarnert : When I try running the program the screen is blank and the prompt does not display. If I don't use def, I end up in a loop that I can't break. I've tried using break,continue, and pass but they have not helped much. I'm still trying to get the hang of this.

Answer (score 0):

1. As mentioned by @rpattiso, you are not invoking the method and
2. You `while` condition is buggy

This should work:

```
def prime_number():
    prime_num = input('Please enter an integer >= 2: ')

    while not (prime_num.isdigit() and not int(prime_num)<1):
        prime_num = input('Please enter an integer >= 2: ')

    for i in range(2,int(prime_num)+1):
        for x in range(2,i):
            if i%x == 0:
                break
        else:
            print (i)
prime_number()
```

Comment: I am not sure why, but I keep getting nothing when I tried running it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *enter* the function.  This is typically done in python with:

```
def prime_number():
    prime_num = input('Please enter an integer >= 2: ')    
    while not(prime_num.isdigit() and int(prime_num)<1):    
        prime_num = input('Please enter an integer >= 2: ')

    for i in range(2,int(prime_num)+1):
        for x in range(2,i):
            if i%x == 0:
                break
        else:
            print (i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    prime_number()
```

Just some advice in general.  I would separate the input logic from the prime number calculation logic.